# Parse.com : More querys from different tables with one API request

Tags: android, sql, performance, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I wanna say if there's a solution to make only one request to receive data from different tables.

**For example:**

I have table "books", "pencils" and another.
I wanna receive only the last row of these tables.

With `ParseObject` i can do a List of ParseObjects and use function `findAllInBackground`. But this function there isn't in PareqQuery Object.

There is a solution?
If I use CloudCode I can make this easy, with less request?

Thanks,Giovanni.

UPDATE: 15 September 2014
My answer is: How I can make different querys ex: "SELECT * FROM BOOK" and "SELECT * FROM PENCILS" with only one request.

My code now is this. but this can take the query from only one table:

```
ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("books");
    query.orderByDescending("id");
    query.setLimit(1);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if(e == null) {
                try {
                    String IDBOOK;
                    try {
                        IDBOOK = parseObjects.get(0).getString("id");
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        IDBOOK = "0";
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error on data received");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query.whereEqualTo` 
Since you are using Parse Object for your Query.

Best Regards